# Imputed values into Shapefile / fortified shapefile

Tags: r, data-imputation

I currently have a shape file with approximately 20 numeric variables. Several of these variables have missing values.

As this is a shapefile I do not think using the median or mean as a form of imputation would be effective.

Is there an approach I can take which would look at the specific polygon with a missing value, and impute that polygon with the mean/median of the surrounding polygons?

I have found the following [paper](https://ij-healthgeographics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1476-072X-13-47):

Baker *et al.*: Missing in space: an evaluation of imputation methods for missing data in spatial analysis of risk factors for type II diabetes. *International Journal of Health Geographics* 2014 **13**:47

which mentions a CAR prior distribution technique- but I am unsure how to implement this technique.

Is there a simplified approach to this spatial imputation technique in r?